# Setting values on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small dataframe, say this one :

```
    Mass32      Mass44  
12  0.576703    0.496159
13  0.576658    0.495832
14  0.576703    0.495398    
15  0.576587    0.494786
16  0.576616    0.494473
...
```

I would like to have a rolling mean of column `Mass32`, so I do this:

```
x['Mass32s'] = pandas.rolling_mean(x.Mass32, 5).shift(-2)
```

It works as in I have a new column named `Mass32s` which contains what I expect it to contain but I also get the warning message:

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try
>   using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

I'm wondering if there's a better way to do it, notably to avoid getting this warning message.

Comment: I don't get the warning message, when I run with your sample code can you check if earlier in your code you've set `x` as a copy of a data frame, something like `x = x[x.Mass32.notnull()]`

Comment: there was a couple of Nas in the dataframe that apparently were messing with me here. Fixing them with fillna(0) and .loc solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This warning comes because your dataframe `x` is a copy of a slice. This is not easy to know why, but it has something to do with how you have come to the current state of it.

You can either create a proper `dataframe` out of x by doing

```
x = x.copy()
```

This will remove the warning, but it is **not the proper way**

You should be using the `DataFrame.loc` method, as the warning suggests, like this:

```
x.loc[:,'Mass32s'] = pandas.rolling_mean(x.Mass32, 5).shift(-2)
```

Comment: there was a couple of Nas in the dataframe that apparently were messing with me here. Fixing them with fillna(0) and .loc solved it. Thanks

Comment: the first method sometimes works... the second method  method gets me the following error     indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key) , in _get_setitem_indexer
    raise IndexingError(key) IndexingError: (slice(None, None, None), 'Mass32s')

Comment: @Lcat sounds like you have none values in the index of your dataframe. Can you make a new question with some example data? and pass it on to me?

Comment: Why is this method better?

Comment: @mxbi copying the dataframe makes a copy, thus doubles the memory used. Even if you overwrite the variable as in my example `x = x.copy()`, there will be a spike in memory usage.