# Why does adding a column to a Pandas DataFrame return a SettingWithCopy warning when the column is a boolean test of an existing column?

Tags: python, pandas

I couldn't find an answer to this in the existing `SettingWithCopy` warning questions, because the common `.loc` solution doesn't seem to apply. I'm loading a table into pandas then trying to create some mask columns based on values in the other columns. For some reason, this returns a `SettingWithCopy` warning even when I'm wrapping the test in a `pd.Series` constructor.

Here's the relevant code. The output at the end seems to be right, but does anyone know what would be causing this?

```
all_invs = pd.read_table('all_quads.inv.bed', index_col=False,
                         header=None, names=clustered_names)

invs = all_invs[all_invs['uniqueIDs'].str.contains('p1')]
samples = [line.strip() for line in open('success_samples.list')]

for sample in samples:
    invs[sample] = invs['uniqueIDs'].str.contains(sample)
```

It happens with another boolean test as well.

```
invs["%s_private_denovo" % proband] = pd.Series(
    invs[proband] & ~invs[father] & ~invs[mother] &
    invs["%s_private" % proband])
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting values on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468176/setting-values-on-a-copy-of-a-slice-from-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

I guess `invs` causes the warning. To resolve that, copy it explicitly like this:

```
invs = all_invs[all_invs['uniqueIDs'].str.contains('p1')].copy()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a copy of the selected answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468176/setting-values-on-a-copy-of-a-slice-from-a-dataframe).

This warning comes because your dataframe `x` is a copy of a slice. This is not easy to know why, but it has something to do with how you have come to the current state of it.

You can either create a proper dataframe out of x by doing

```
x = x.copy()
```

This will remove the warning, but **it is not the proper way**!

You should be using the `DataFrame.loc` method, as the warning suggests, like this:

```
x.loc[:,'Mass32s'] = pandas.rolling_mean(x.Mass32, 5).shift(-2)
```