# Copy of a Dataframe results to SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I’m trying to add a new column to my DataFrame `Transactions_Meat`:

```
   Transactions_Meat['Avg_IPrice'] = Transactions_Meat['Rev'] / Transactions_Meat['Units_Sold']
```

Resulting to this *warning*:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

`Transactions_Meat` is a copy of a DataFrame named `Transactions`:

```
Transactions_Meat = Transactions[Transactions['Category'] == 'Meat']
```

So, im trying to use `.loc` which changed my approach to:

```
Transactions_Meat.loc[:,'Avg_IPrice'] = Transactions_Meat['Rev'] / Transactions_Meat['Units_Sold']
```

Unfortunately, I’m still getting the same *warning*. I've visited the documentation of pandas as described [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy). I also checked the [stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) which is already handling this problem. But I couldn’t get rid of the warning.

Any possbility to remove the warning using the DataFrame.loc method?

Comment: How have you defined `Transactions_Meat` earlier in your code. Is it a slice of another dataframe?

Comment: @jpp I've edited according to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is ambiguous:

```
Transactions_Meat = Transactions[Transactions['Category'] == 'Meat']
```

If you want a copy, be explicit and use [`pd.DataFrame.copy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html):

```
Transactions_Meat = Transactions[Transactions['Category'] == 'Meat'].copy()
```

This should remove the subsequent warnings, as well as guarantee that you original `Transactions` dataframe will not be modified when you manipulate `Transactions_Meat`.

Comment: This will indeed remove the warning. But as mentioned in the stackoverflow-answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31468176/setting-values-on-a-copy-of-a-slice-from-a-dataframe?rq=1), copy() is not the proper way.

Comment: @JustinScofield, The question there is different. Here you **want** a copy. In that question, OP does not want a copy and therefore `copy()` is inappropriate.